# I can't get the users location because an error I cannot figure out

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure what is wrong with my following code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

LocationManager locationManager;
String provider; //store gps provider

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //get location of user
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);       //false to check if available ourselves

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null){
        Log.i("Location info:", "Location achieved!");
    }
    else{
        Log.i("Location info:", "No location");
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);       //(provider, miliseconds, meters, context)

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

}

@Override   //gives location as soon as it changes or updates
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();

    Log.i("Latitude", String.valueOf(lat));
    Log.i("Longitude", String.valueOf(lng));
}

@Override       //when location comes available
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override       //when gps is available
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override       //when gps is disabled
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```

I get this error everytime I run it

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.jimmy.locationdemo, PID: 19373
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jimmy.locationdemo/com.example.jimmy.locationdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
>                                                                                       at android.location.LocationManager.checkProvider(LocationManager.java:1828)
>                                                                                       at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1275)
>                                                                                       at com.example.jimmy.locationdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6279)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)

I have written the permission in the manifest as well. Maybe I'm using the wrong API?

If someone can point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Comment: Does `locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);` return a valid String?

Comment: I believe so. I'm following a video tutorial and it works for him..

Comment: I would check it, because your log says `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null at `... Just output the string to the log.

Comment: I checked and you're right. It does not return a valid String.

Comment: Okay, so now you can explore why it's not valid... I'm not sure why. Could have something to do with permissions or the `new Criteria()` object.

Comment: Thakns for the help. I'll get on that